# List all categories in layered navigation block Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi I am trying to display all categories within the layered navigation block, the default just returns subcategories of the current parent.

What i would like to do is display all categories for every category page within the filters of the layered nav.

Any ideas i have no clue where to start

Answer (score 0):

But it doesn't make sense. If you are in some category you should not see products from category which is not it's sub-category.